# What plant is this? And how can I prevent it from dying?

Tags: identification, yucca

We've not overwatered it (we don't think) and have owned these plants for two years. In the space of a week these started to wilt.

The right hand plant has a soft stem at the bottom.

Is it possible to transplant these?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These are [Yucca Gigantea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yucca_gigantea).  They are really tough plants that will survive a lot of neglect and even low light.
When grown in full sun with a light hand on the watering the foliage is a dark green and the stems can be as thick as your arm

These plants must have good drainage or the stems get soft and rot.  Excellent light from a south facing window is a good idea as well.

It would be a good idea to repot them into a soil less mix for cacti or succulents as that drains better.  You could probably put both into one smaller pot than they have now.  A smaller pot dries out faster.

Comment: getting a growlight might be helpful in getting the plants healthy again,a good growlight will produce mainly blue and red light that the plants need to stay healthy.